# How to auto indent full javascript project?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, auto-indent, tooling

I want to auto-indent a full javascript project. How can I do that using WebStorm or another tool?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is it multiple files? Is the javascript in HTML files or separate files, etc?

Comment: I know ^ + alt + I, but it just does the selection. I want something for the full project (javascript). Not just one file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select your project root folder/source root folder in the Project tool window on the left
2. From main menu choose Code | Reformat Code (or hit `Ctrl+Alt+L`)

Answer (score 0):

This [project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) called js-beautify could help you. It exists as an npm or python package.

You can then use find to iterate over all the js files in your directory :

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec js-beautify -r {} \;
```

**Warning** : it will indent all the js files, and will overwrite the original files. Be sure to have commited those files to svn/git before you try the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Create file in your project root: .editorconfig with content

```
# http://editorconfig.org
root = true
[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

Adjust ident_size for yourself.

Restart WebStorm, accept that WebStrom should use editor config file.

Click: **ctrl+alt+L**

Or: **Code > Reformat code**